# Chrome Remote Desktop on Windows 2012R2 Virtual Machine at Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012R2 instance running at GCE and successfully can log in via "Chrome RDP", a Chrome RDP client that is launched by the Developer Console if you click on RDP. I also used the "Chrome RDP" Chrome Web Store App via an ssh tunnel to a linux instance in the same project and network.

I then installed Google Chrome and set up access via "Chrome Remote Desktop", but when I access the box, the screen is just a big black square. I think this is all related to the fact that there is no "Display Adapter" section in the "Device Manager".

I'm hoping someone could tell me what the requirements are to run "Chrome Remote Desktop" on a virtual machine with no monitor installed that has no "Display Adapter" drivers.

Comment: The only solution I have found is to switch to using Microsoft Azure - chrome remote client works there as expected, no problems on any of my devices

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue as I was able to remote into my VM using the "Chrome Remote Desktop". The only thing I could think of is that you might need to update Chrome and Remote Desktop App.

Another thing to try is to create a new Windows 2012R2 instance and see if you can use the Chrome Remote Desktop to log into it before making any changes to the instance.